# Git access on Heroku deployment and others: connection refused

Tags: ssh, heroku

I have suddenly run into an issue using git.

I created a new app, went to push to Heroku and now see:

```
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection refused
```

My other previously working Heroku apps no longer work, receiving the same error.
Other Heroku commands work (create, info, db:push).

I also see the error when accessing Git on my unfuddle accounts.

I can SSH to other services, so it doesn't look like it's my machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: any changes to your system lately?  have you upgraded ruby or git or anything else?

what happens when you run "heroku logs"...



do you owe them money???  kidding...

Comment: also, it's a strange error message, since it specifically references 'ssh', which is something I've never seen in the heroku console.  what OS are you on?

Comment: Glitch in the MAtrix. It all works again now. V.strange indeed.

Comment: I added the ssh tag because it's relevant to the problem, and removed the ruby-on-rails tag because it wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted and problem solved.

Comment: And the problem is happening again. The only thing I have installed recently is RVM, I wonder if that is causing the problem.

Comment: Have you had any success with this since then? I've got no resolution to the same issue.. and NOBODY on the interwebs seems to have it either.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049900/cannot-push-git-to-remote-repository-ssh-error

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049900/cannot-push-git-to-remote-repository-ssh-error/4049963#4049963) might help. Matt H. suffered the same problem of connection refused errors when connecting to heroku.com, because he was running PeerGuardian. Heroku's staff say that "Most of the time, we find users who have software that is blocking ec2/amazon."