# ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: heroku, connection, timeout

I am working on Ubuntu 11.10
Local branch of my git-repo is up to date

I then wrote following command in terminal:

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

And this error was printed:

```
Notice: on Wed, 20 June, our default stack will change to Cedar. <Shortened Blog URL>

Creating radiant-wind-7413... done, stack is cedar  
http://radiant-wind-7413.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:radiant-wind-7413.git  
Git remote heroku added
```

[Blog URL on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120705054711/http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/24/cedar_goes_ga/)<sup>1</sup>

All fine till now, then I typed following in terminal:

```
git push heroku master
```

and the following error occured:

```
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection timed out  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note: Shortened URL were allowed in 2012 but [shortened URLs have now been blacklisted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts)

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742937/rails-heroku-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly

Answer (score 21):

As of November 30, 2021, the SSH Git Transport feature has been deprecated by Heroku and only HTTP transport is supported. The real shutdown of SSH was in March 2022.

You have to reconfigure the repo with :

```
heroku git:remote -a <app-name>
```

[Official statement from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2301)

If you are using a remote with a different name, e.g. `production` then use

```
heroku git:remote -a <app-name> -r <remote-name>
```

Maybe you will have to unset ssh connections on git global config :

```
git config --global --unset url.ssh://git@heroku/.insteadof
git config --global --unset url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadof
```

Comment: It would be helpful to enrich this type of answers with a link to the documentation that confirms what you're writing!

Comment: This sort of works, but it does not work out of the box if you are using remotes, such as staging and production app.  The heroku git:remote command creates a new remote heroku, so instead using ```git push production master``` you need to do ```git push heroku master```.  I would be useful if someone extends this answer to describe how to fix the problem if your remote names are not heroku.

Answer (score 6):

Most probably some sort of firewall issue or your network admin has blocked outgoing port 22 in your network.

You may use simple scrip to see your connection to Heroku by :

`$ ssh -vvv git@heroku.com`

If you seeing connect timed out then you may need to request your admin to unblock port 22. Alternatively may access Heroku via **tunneling** as per my answer in [Connecting to heroku using port 443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877088/connecting-to-heroku-using-port-443/19536371#19536371)

Answer (score 5):

I had the similar problem with keys. Ok this is what I did.

Check the status of your keys with

```
heroku keys
```

It shows you list of keys that are added to heroku. You can always generate new keys and add them to heroku.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Generates new key.

`heroku keys:add`

adds the keys to heroku. Before adding it lists the available keys that you can add. Enter the option and you key is added to heroku.

[This article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) can be helpful. If that doesn't work then there should be some problem with ssh. Try doing an ssh localhost and see if ssh is working.

Answer (score 2):

Today Heroku uses git over ssh.  The default port for ssh is 22 and it looks like your network doesn't allow outbound connections to port 22.  Perhaps this is something your network administrator can change.

Comment: For some company it is very difficult to deal with company's Administrator / policy any alternative to this ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @JamesWard but if I"m just doing this from home who exactly is the network administrator? I'm very confused as to how this literally worked 5 hours ago and suddenly stopped. Nothing about my setup has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I had been working on this for hours trying to figure out how I could suddenly have a closed port 22, etc. when literally 5 hours ago everything was working and nothing had changed.

Finally I just reset my Git repo on Heroku and repushed everything. Still no idea what happened.

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
heroku repo:reset --app appname
```

Comment: I had the same experience today but this did not work for me. I was able to push again after switching from ssh to https remote connection.

Comment: Switching to https worked for me too.  See https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2301

Comment: yeah as of May 1 2022, the deprecation appears to have really kicked in, @novastra's answer is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
heroku keys:add
heroku keys  # lists keys
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the https url to the .git/config file in my project folder. I found the HTTPS URL in the project Settings on Heroku. I then added that URL to replace the SSH url inside the .git/config text file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me helped destroying whole app and recreating again - leaving it here for future reference.

```
heroku apps:destroy appname
heroku apps:create appname
heroku git:remote -a appname
git push heroku master
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31328902)