# Need help cloning collaborative git repository - getting host is down error

Tags: git, heroku, git-clone

Trying to clone a git repo I've been asked to collaborate on and keep getting this error

ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Host is down
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Any ideas? Really need to get this working! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a proxy issue, or it can be because you didn't add your ssh public key to the repo (as mentioned in "[ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968591/ssh-connect-to-host-heroku-com-port-22-connection-timed-out)").
Depending on your ssh address, use the [right ssh config for heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555546/error-in-git-push-heroku-master-through-ssh-behind-proxy).

Make sure your heroku repo address is the right one (see "[Rails / Heroku: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742937/rails-heroku-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)").

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ended up being some issues around the ssh public key.