# git push heroku master gives error ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection refused

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to run the heroku-django tutorial (using ubuntu 12.04) and it seems for some reason i cant push into heroku. here is what happens:

```
yeinhorn@ubuntu:~/hellodjango$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/yeinhorn/hellodjango/.git/
yeinhorn@ubuntu:~/hellodjango$ git add .
yeinhorn@ubuntu:~/hellodjango$ git commit -m "my first commit"
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
yeinhorn@ubuntu:~/hellodjango$ heroku create
Creating high-dusk-6308... done, stack is cedar
http://high-dusk-6308.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:high-dusk-6308.git
 !    New default stack: Cedar. To use Bamboo, run `heroku create -s bamboo`.
yeinhorn@ubuntu:~/hellodjango$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:blazing-dusk-8587.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:blazing-dusk-8587.git (push)
yeinhorn@ubuntu:~/hellodjango$ git push heroku master
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
yeinhorn@ubuntu:~/hellodjango$ git push -f heroku
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung
```

up unexpectedly

also when i run

```
$telnet heroku.com 22
```

i get

```
Trying 50.19.85.132...
Trying 50.19.85.154...
Trying 50.19.85.156...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please format your copy paste terminal output in a code block. See: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444643/git-access-on-heroku-deployment-and-others-connection-refused) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049900/cannot-push-git-to-remote-repository-ssh-error), I'd suggest you check that you don't have any firewall or port blocking software running (like PeerGaurdian) and that you're nto blocking Amazon/EC2 anywhere on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Do following steps:1. check sshd service:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa   # created ssh key
$ heroku keys:add   # upload ssh key
$ heroku keys  # lists keys
```

2. find a normal proxy node

```
$ ssh -vvv heroku.com  # debug ssh connection
$ vim ~/.ssh/config   # setup usefull proxy node
  Host heroku.com
  Hostname 107.21.95.3     # trans by ip
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  port 22
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am from China and many programmers here suffered this problem by the GFW(Great firewall). I have solved my connection timed out problem by setting the ssh config file as you said. But I wonder how you know 107.21.95.3 is available, how do you get that ip, what's that ip represent and if that ip is no available in the future, how can I find the other one.

Comment: I'll always here, you can follow it