# Can't push commit - operation timed out

Tags: heroku

First of all; I am trying to set up hubot with [this manual](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/deploying/heroku.md) and it worked 12 days ago. Today I tried committing some changes and it failed again and again so I started from the beginning. This are the steps I did:

```
sudo gem uninstall heroku
// then I installed heroku toolbelt thinking that this could be the problem

rm -rf /Users/andrei/.ssh/*rsa*
heroku login
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "first"
heroku create
// then I did all the config stuff, etc.
git push heroku master
```

And here everything breaks. I get this after hanging about 10, 15 minutes:

```
zippy-one:franjo andrei$ git push heroku master
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

OK, I will debug the SSH:

```
zippy-one:franjo andrei$ ssh -vvv heroku.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/andrei/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.154] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.19.85.154 port 22: Operation timed out
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.156] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.19.85.156 port 22: Operation timed out
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.132] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.19.85.132 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

Now what I think it could have braked this is that I changed my hostname. But then again I recreated the keys and everything fits when comparing to `heroku keys`.

Can you please help me? I am way over my head here and I am stuck. Thank you in advance!

**Additional info:**

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168279/git-push-heroku-master-gives-error-ssh-connect-to-host-heroku-com-port-22-conn?rq=1) and tried everything there, as you can see up there. No firewall is blocking any connections from ssh, or to Amazon's servers.

Comment: https://status.heroku.com/ No known issues at this time. so maybe the problem is in your network

Comment: Yeah, I checked that. I will try using my mobile phone, just to rule this out.
**Edit:** It seems that it is up to my network. I will check this out further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ISP was blocking heroku for some reason? Well there is that then.

Answer (score 1):

**CAUSE:** My remote fetch/push URL for heroku got screwed up and fixing that solved the problem for me.

**EXPLANATION:** Heroku was trying to push the git repository to an address where it didn't exist (or was formatted wrong), and thus timed out in the process.

**SOLUTION:** Verify in Terminal you have the correct remote URL for pushing to heroku, and then change it if necessary:

---

Steps:

**1. Enter your git folder**

```
cd /path/to/my/git/project
```

**2. Check remote URLs**

```
git remote -v
```

**3. Inspect the output**

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:my-heroku-app.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:my-heroku-app.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:my-git-username/my-heroku-app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:my-git-username/my-heroku-app.git (push)
```

The above is what it *should* look like. In my case, the top two lines were formatted as `git@heroku.my-heroku-app` instead of `git@heroku.com`. When I changed them, it stopped timing out.

---

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I've had that happen when pushing a Rails app to Heroku containing a new image file and not doing a 'rake assets:precompile'